# How to open multipage XLS sheet in PhoneGap iOS App

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

How can I open multipage XLS sheet in PhoneGap iOS App?

One method is by using in-app browser:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('yourFileUrl', '_blank');
```

But by using this method, it opens single page excel sheet; but, for multi-page XLS files, it shows only the page title.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! I made a couple of edits to your question, mostly related to formatting and grammar. Please look over what I edited and take this into account for future posts. Thanks for your question!